# Get newest value of an array

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I would like to show custom posts as an "issues" page. I can hard code the 'terms', e.g. `issue-3`, but how can I display just the newest one?

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'issue_filter',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                // 'terms'    => 'category' this is good
                'terms'    => 'issue-3'
            )
        )
    )
);
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Since WP_Query already orders by `post_date DESC` by default, if you just want the latest `news` post type with that taxonomy, just set `posts_per_page => 1`

Comment: Thanks. If I needed to call the issues dynamically how would I do that? I have that hard coded at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to get the most recent term from your `issue_filter` taxonomy. To do that you'd want to use [`get_terms()` with a few arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters).

```
$t = get_terms(
  'issue_filter',
  array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'number' => 1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
  )
);
```

That should get you the most recently created term with content as an array of IDs. Your [`tax_query` will accept that array](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) as is, so...

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'issue_filter',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $t
            )
        )
    )
);
```